# Calculating SumIfs from another tab

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

I would like to know please if there is an efficient way to re-write the code I did. Basically it calculates the `SumIfs` from another tab depending on the tab the user pointed to, in row number 3, so each time something changed in row number 3 it should recalculate all again.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error Resume Next

Dim Amount As Range 'the range i want to sum
Dim ID As Range 'criteria range
Dim Arg3 As Variant 'the criteria
Dim TabToTake As String
Dim countAllActiveCell As Long
Dim CellsCnt As Range

Dim ActiveCol

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:XFD3")) Is Nothing Then

ActiveCol = Left(ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Address(False, False), InStr(1, ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Address(False, False), ":") - 1)

TabToTake = ActiveCell.Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Set ID = Sheets(TabToTake).Range("A:A")
  Set Amount = Sheets(TabToTake).Range("Q:Q")

For Each CellsCnt In Range("E4:E2500").Cells
    If Not IsEmpty(CellsCnt) Then

        Cells(CellsCnt.Row, ActiveCol).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Amount, ID, Cells(CellsCnt.Row, "E").Value)

    End If
Next CellsCnt

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, in this case, there's no real reason to use the worksheet function if you're not putting the function into the cell.

---

#### Flawed Worksheet_Change structure

This here -

> ```
> ActiveCol = Left(ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Address(False, False), InStr(1, ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Address(False, False), ":") - 1)
> ```

Only works ***on*** the worksheet change, so if you don't go directly to the next cell (vertically), you get the wrong column. Try it -

```
ActiveCol = Left(ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Address(False, False), InStr(1, ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Address(False, False), ":") - 1)
MsgBox ActiveCol
```

It's the column wherever the *current cell is* selected, since the **change doesn't occur until you leave the cell**, not where the *target cell was*. Not sure why you need the letter, so just get the column number -

```
ActiveCol = Target.Column
MsgBox ActiveCol
```

This works on your target that changed, not where your cursor ended up. Small, but important.

This also matters for your `TabToTake` using ActiveCell, are you sure you want to take the next cell's value, which best case scenario, will be on row 4?

**That's why you pass `Target` into the function** - to use it as a variable. I know that seems pretty obvious when I point it out, but I also know how confusing `Target` can be if you're just starting out, so don't sweat it.

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Rows(3)) Is Nothing Then
    targetSheet = Sheets(Target.Value)
    activeColumn = Target.Column
```

---

You haven't qualified everything -

> ```
> For Each CellsCnt In Range("E4:E2500").Cells
> ```

I imagine that should be on the current sheet, but *tell me* that.

---

Let's break down the meat of your sub

```
Set ID = Sheets(TabToTake).Range("A:A")
Set Amount = Sheets(TabToTake).Range("Q:Q")
For Each CellsCnt In Range("E4:E2500").Cells
    If Not IsEmpty(CellsCnt) Then
        Cells(CellsCnt.Row, ActiveCol).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Amount, ID, Cells(CellsCnt.Row, "E").Value)
    End If
Next CellsCnt
```

First, For every cell in column E on targetSheet, if it isn't empty THEN

targetSheet, of that cell, in the ActiveCol (which is not `target`) =

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(targetSheet.Range("Q:Q"), targetSheet.Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.Cells(CellsCnt.Row, 5)).Value
```

So what are we doing here, exactly.

> Summing all of targetSheet.Columns("G") if all of targetSheet.Columns("A") = current cell. FOR ALL OF COLUMN E.

Assuming that a lot of column E changes when something in row 3 changes, you essentially do a sum of vlookups yeah? Hm, why do that so much? Not knowing how your cells are linked up in your sheet, makes it more difficult to really optimize this, but here's a try

```
Const LOOKUP_COLUMN As Long = 5
Const LOOK_IN_COLUMN As Long = 1
Const SUM_COLUMN As Long = 17
Dim lookupVector As Variant
Dim lookinVector As Variant
Dim sumVector As Variant
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, LOOKUP_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Row
lookupVector = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(4, LOOKUP_COLUMN), Cells(lastRow, LOOKUP_COLUMN))

lastRow = targetSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, LOOK_IN_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Row
lookinVector = targetSheet.Range(Cells(1, LOOK_IN_COLUMN), Cells(lastRow, LOOK_IN_COLUMN))
sumVector = targetSheet.Range(Cells(1, SUM_COLUMN), Cells(lastRow, SUM_COLUMN))
```

Now everything is in arrays and you can perform your calculations behind the scenes, much faster -

```
Dim resultVector() As Double
Dim result As Double
ReDim resultVector(LBound(lookupVector) To UBound(lookupVector))
Dim index As Long
Dim targetIndex As Long
For index = LBound(lookupVector) To UBound(lookupVector)
    result = 0
    For targetIndex = LBound(lookinVector) To UBound(lookinVector)
        If lookinVector(index) = lookupVector(index) Then result = result + sumVector(targetIndex)
    Next
    resultVector(index) = result
Next
```

Once you're done, you just put that resultVector back in your lookup_column.

---

#### Variables

Give your variables *meaningful names*. When I see `Amount` in code, I don't assume it's a *Range* I assume it's a *Value*. Make that clear, it's easier on future you. You can see my examples of changes in the code above.

[Standard VBA naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s46s4ew(v=vs.140).aspx) have `camelCase` for local variables and `PascalCase` for other variables and names.

> ```
> Dim ActiveCol
> ```

You didn't give this variable a *type* so it was declared as a variant. You don't need a variant, just a simple `long`.

---

#### Indenting

It's good practice to indent *all of your code* that way `Labels` will stick out as obvious.

---

#### Error Handling

This

> ```
> On Error Resume Next
> ```

What error is that handling? What *can* go wrong? For instance, when you were using the selection instead of the target, you wouldn't see that it didn't *do* what it was supposed to do. Handle your errors specifically so you know what can go wrong, how it goes wrong and how to prevent it.

---

#### Working on the sheet

Working with the ranges instead of arrays - it just slows the code down by needing to fiddle with the spreadsheet while doing everything else behind the scenes. There's a good question on StackOverflow [addressing this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros). The same logic applies here.

---

#### Comments

Comments - ["code tell you how, comments tell you why"](http://blog.codinghorror.com/code-tells-you-how-comments-tell-you-why/). The code should speak for itself, if it needs a comment, it might need to be made more clear. If not, the comment should describe *why* you're doing something rather than *how* you're doing it. Here are a [few reasons](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/254979/125931) to avoid comments all together.

> ```
> Dim Amount As Range 'the range i want to sum
> Dim ID As Range 'criteria range
> Dim Arg3 As Variant 'the criteria
> ```

You telling me in comments what ranges do what, that was your first indication that your naming could be improved, right?

---

#### Method

Like I said, I don't know the exact structure of your sheets, but maybe `Worksheet_Change` isn't the best way in which to do these calculations. Think about what changes and when it changes and see if there's a more efficient way to do it instead of *every time* there's a change.

Honestly, maybe your best bet is actually using the `SUMIFS` function, like

```
 =IFERROR("",SUMIFS(Sheet1!A1:A31,Sheet1!Q1:Q25,Sheet2!E7))
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for this long answer,
what i'm basically looking for is that:
I have a few tabs with data each tab is in the same structure,
lets say, column A is account number , column B is Month (Jan , Feb etc) column C is amount.

now in the main tab as you can see in the pic Column E contain the account numbers and column G to R are like that,row number 1 is the month for the sumifs criteria row number 3 is the tab name to take the data from.
now I want when the user change the name of the tab in row 3 it will sumifs from this tab in all the column also when the user change the account number in column E it will change also all the rows in this account based on the tab to take in row number 3.

what do you say?

[image: main tab]